# Difference between "cmd" and "comm" in ps command

Tags: ps, xubuntu

I'm new to bash and Linux and have a question. My problem is that I want to print a process name by its pid. I've googled and found few ways to do it:

- `ps -p <PID> -o cmd`
- `ps -p <PID> -o comm`

etc. I'm using Xubutnu 14.04 and first command (on an arbitrary pid) showed me:

> CMD
>
> x-session-manager

and the second one:

> COMMAND
>
> x-session-manag

as you can see second name is not full. Plus, they both have a column name. I found that adding `=` at the end of the command would make column name disappear. I've read `man ps` but could not understand the real difference between `comm` and `cmd` (because on explanation on both of them was `alias` ).

What are the differences between the `cmd` and `comm` flags to `ps -o`?

Comment: `comm` is the name of the command run(truncated to n characters), i.e the name of the file/executable. `cmd` is the full command line of the command.

Comment: using `=` is strange...you need one per entry in the format string. I just use `--no-header` which applies to all.

Comment: How can I get only process name without command line arguments? or how can I truncate to for example 10 characters using comm?

Comment: comm just outputs whatever is in /proc/PID/comm, it is already truncated, `Strings longer than TASK_COMM_LEN (16) characters are silently truncated.` from proc man page

Answer (score 2):

According to `man ps` (for `ps` from `procps-ng 3.3.12`) the option `comm` shows only the executable name without showing the modification of the command name, while `cmd` shows command name with arguments as a string and possibly could show the modification of the command arguments.

When this commands specified last, they show output string to the edge of the display, so the name could be truncated. Truncating of the output to `N` columns could be done with `--cols <N>` command, clearing header with `--no-header`, like this

```
ps -p <PID> -o comm --cols <N> --no-header
```

Comment: thank you very much for reply but `ps -p 29789 -o comm --cols 100 --no-header` shows me `x-session-manag` instead of a full name.

Comment: @user180394 Do you have root permission?

Comment: yes I use `sudo`

Comment: @user180394 try `sudo readlink /proc/PID/exe`

Comment: that worked, thank you very much, but is there any way without using sudo?

Comment: @user180394 Could try `awk -vRS="\0" 'NR==1' /proc/PID/cmdline`

Comment: Have you used `c` option: `ps c -p <PID> -o comm --cols <N> --no-header`?

Comment: @KonstantinMorenko comm is truncated before ps even sees it. No option is going to add more characters.